# Create multiple tables on a database

Tags: php, database, pdo

Using PHP to create tables on a database with `$fsdbh` containing the database. Obviously I am missing something.

```
function createdb($tables){
    global $fsdbh;
    $sth = $fsdbh->prepare('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS system');
    $sth->execute();
}
```

This function is causing a blank screen when triggered.

The intention is to use the function to create a series of tables:

```
function createdb($tables){
    global $fsdbh;
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS system';
    foreach($tables as $table){
       $sql.= '; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table';
    }
    $sth = $fsdbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

How would we get this to work?

Comment: What messages do you have in your server log ?

Comment: `$fsdbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING); error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - blank screen = 500 error (probably) = error message telling you what went wrong.

Comment: I guess that the missing C in `REATE TABLE IF` is a typo...

Comment: Also note that you can't pass multiple queries to `prepare()`, you have to run them all separately. Also there's not much point in preparing DDL statements, they don't (shouldn't) take user input.

Comment: In fact looking at the above code, your query will be failing, you can't run `CREATE TABLE` without defining at least the column structure

Comment: you should add some error handling.. personally I think that the best way would be to set error mode to throwing exceptions and wrap the executions in a try/catch block.. after that you can just check the error message.. If I were to guess I think that this might be a problem related to the fact that the table is named system.. try using it between backtrick operators (\`system\`)

Comment: @mishu I suspect it already is throwing an exception because of the "blank screen" effect

Comment: @DaveRandom yes, you are right.. fatal error caused by uncaught exception

Comment: display errors shows uncaught exceptions as well. no need to disable exceptions for that.